# Xamarin Forms toolbar not showing on Android

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a ContentPage that is accessed via a TabPage's child, it is simply accessed via a click of a button.
On iOS, the page has a toolbar

[image: iOS Toolbar]

However on Android, there isn't one displayed. I have to rely on the user to use the back button on their device.

How can I get this to display on Android?
I have tried using several fixes including: `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);` but this makes no difference.

Comment: Try removing `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`.

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled.  I mean I used:             NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
I have tried removing it too and it doesn't work

Comment: You can try wrapping your page in navigation page  `Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new yourPage()));` when pushing it.

Comment: Can you tell us how you set up your tabs in the TabbedPage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable hierarchical navigation from a tab you just need to wrap those tabs in a NavigationPage, like so:

```
public partial class TabPage : TabbedPage
{
    Page TabOne;
    Page TabTwo;
    Page TabThree;

    public TabPage()
    {
        TabOne = new NavigationPage(new TabOnePage());
        TabTwo = new NavigationPage(new TabTwoPage());
        TabThree = new NavigationPage(new TabThreePage());

        Children.Add(homePage);
        Children.Add(resourcesPage);
        Children.Add(helpPage);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.